# MultiBitHD gap limit multiple devices

Tags: bitcoin-core, client, multibit-hd

A technical question on MBHD gap limit. Afaic the gap limit (GL) is to warn a user to not create a too large gap between the last actively used address and newly (unused) addresses. Now, suppose I'm sharing the same wallet on two different devices (eg. mobile phone and laptop). Both of them will use the same GL. Isn't there a chance that both will start to use the same address at the same time? Suppose that I hit the request payment on both my mobile device and laptop on more or less the same time (within a second). How do they know that they are not using the same address? Is that information maybe shared via MB servers? Or is using the same address on multiple devices not a problem as they are both owned by me anyway